# How can I add additional value to variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add dates to a slider and need to increment the values on click.  I currently start with the year `- 2`

```
$('#adddates').click(function() {
    var year = 2;
    $("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
        bounds: {
            min: new Date(Today.getFullYear() - ++year, 0, 1),
            max: new Date(Today.getFullYear(), Today.getMonth(), Today.getDate())
        }
    });
});
```

On click I am only getting an additional year.  I need to increase the number of the year variable from 2 on each click.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: You need some sort of global to maintain client state.

Comment: On click you are getting an additional year, meaning **one**. That is evident when using `++year`. So can you clarify what you mean then by saying *increase the number of the year variable from 2*? Do you mean using `year += 2` ?

Comment: He wants to maintain the state of year such that it doesn't get reset, at least that is what it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to maintain the year value declare it outside of your click event:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var year = 2; // abstracting the year away from the click function
    $('#adddates').click(function() {
        $("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
            bounds: {
                min: new Date(Today.getFullYear() - ++year, 0, 1),
                max: new Date(Today.getFullYear(), Today.getMonth(), Today.getDate())
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please note however, if for any reason you do some sort of server side post back this value will be reset.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to keep it inside the `$(document).ready` but outside the `$("#adddates').click(function` ?